# Single Pass Seed Selection Algorithm for k-Means

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I've recently read the [Single Pass Seed Selection Algorithm for k-Means](http://thescipub.com/pdf/10.3844/jcssp.2010.60.66) article, but not really understand the algorithm, which is:

1. Calculate distance matrix `Dist` in which `Dist (i,j)` represents distance from `i` to `j`
2. Find `Sumv` in which `Sumv (i)` is the sum of the distances from `i`th point to all other points.
3. Find the point `i` which is `min (Sumv)` and set `Index = i`
4. Add First to `C` as the first centroid
5. For each point `xi`, set `D (xi)` to be the distance between `xi` and the nearest point in `C`
6. Find `y` as the sum of distances of first `n/k` nearest points from the `Index`
7. Find the unique integer `i` so that `D(x1)^2+D(x2)^2+...+D(xi)^2 >= y > D(x1)^2+D(x2)^2+...+D(x(i-1))^2`
8. Add `xi` to `C`
9. Repeat steps 5-8 until `k` centers

Especially step 6, do we still use the same `Index` (same point) over and over or we use the newly added point from `C`? And about step 8, does `i` have to be larger than `1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't worry about understanding that paper - its not very good.

- The algorithm is poorly described.
- Its not actually a single pass, it needs do to n^2/2 pairwise computations + one additional pass through the data.
- They don't report the runtime of their seed selection scheme, probably because it is very bad doing O(n^2) work.
- They are evaluating on very simple data sets that don't have a lot of bad solutions for k-Means to fall into.
- One of their metrics of "better"ness is how many iterations it takes k-means to run given the seed selection. While it is an interesting metric, the small differences they report are meaningless (k-means++ seeding could be more iterations, but less work done per iteration), and they don't report the run time or which k-means algorithm they use.

You will get a lot more benefit from learning and understanding the k-means++ algorithm they are comparing against, and reading some of the history from that.

If you really want to understand what they are doing, I would brush up on your matlab and read their provided matlab code. But its not really worth it. If you look up the quantile seed selection algorithm, they are essentially doing something very similar. Instead of using the distance to the first seed to sort the points, they appear to be using the sum of pairwise distances (which means they don't need an initial seed, hence the unique solution).

Comment: So this is not a good algorithm for seeding? Do you have any good paper/article about K-means++?

Comment: No, it does not seem to be. Google is your friend, the original paper for k-mean++ is a good place to start. https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring07/cps296.2/papers/kMeansPlusPlus.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Single Pass Seed Selection algorithm is a novel algorithm. Single Pass mean that without any iterations first seed can be selected. k-means++ performance is depends on first seed. It is overcome in SPSS. Please gothrough the paper "Robust Seed Selestion Algorithm for k-means" from the same authors

John J. Louis